# dotENV file and it's content looks black and cannot modify anything in it in my Laravel Project

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I don't understand the reason behind this. Can it be related to PHP extensions?
Since I created the project I see my .env file's content looks like that. I cannot modify anything in it.
What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Most likely a setting or plugin from your IDE (VSC? PHPstorm?) Greyed out because `.env` is in `.gitignore`.

Comment: I use VSC, that's interesting. If that's the case it's really hard to find which plugin causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

In VS Code,I just typed “Toggle auto-cloaking” at the top and now all the black lines are gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

To add additional info to this: if you're using the `Dotenv Official +Vault` extension in VS Code, the `autocloaking` option is on by default.

Go to the settings for the extension, and uncheck the `Dotenv: Enable Autocloaking` option.
[screenshot of DotEnv VS Code extension settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f6wO.png)

You can reference the documentation for the plugin here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dotenv.dotenv-vscode

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using DotEnv extension on your VSCode.
You can toggle it off by click on this
[image]

Else you can remove that extension or change setting like
Search for cloak and change cloaking color or toggle it off.